# C stdout alternative

Tags: c, mingw, stdout

I'm using a library for my project. This library sometimes prints some messages to stdout. This is a problem for me because the messages are mixed up along with the application messages. It will be useful to a stop this behaviour or have them printed to a different window. I'm using C Language and Mingw32 enviroment. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Library functions generally shouldn't write to `stdout` unless that's the purpose of the function. Are you sure it's not writing to `stderr`?

Comment: In this case the library write to stdout because if I insert a "fclose(stderr)" nothing is happening, else I close the stdout the screen is clean.

Comment: Is your application single-threaded, and guaranteed to be only single-threaded?  If so, it's possible to wrap all calls to this perverse library with calls that redirect `stdout` to some other destination, call the library, then restore `stdout`.  If your application or the library is multithreaded, there's no safe way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to (nonportably) swap the `stdout` with another stream:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *devnull;
#define SWAPSTDOUT() do{ FILE *tmp = stdout;  stdout = devnull; devnull = tmp; }while(0)

int main(void)
{
    /*program initialization*/
    if(0==(devnull= fopen("/dev/null", "r"))) return 1;

    fputs("your code 0\n",stdout);
    SWAPSTDOUT();
    fputs("library code 0\n",stdout); //should be silent
    SWAPSTDOUT();
    fputs("your code 1\n", stdout);
}
```

Unfortunately, that's unlikely to work with functions that hardcode `stdout` (e.g., `printf` or `puts`).

If you're on a POSIX platform, you might have `freopen` but that won't help much if you can't save the original stream. However, on POSIX you could `fflush(stdout)` and then shuffle the underlying file descriptors, which should be quite reliable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int devnull, tmp;
int swapstdout(void);

int main(void)
{
    /*program initialization*/
    if(0>(devnull=open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY))) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if(0>(tmp=dup(devnull))) return EXIT_FAILURE; //reserve a fd spot


    fputs("your code 0\n",stdout);
    if(0>swapstdout()) return EXIT_FAILURE:
    fputs("library code 0\n",stdout); //should be silent
    if(0>swapstdout()) return EXIT_FAILURE:
    fputs("your code 1\n", stdout);
}

int swapstdout(void)
{
    if(0>fflush(stdout)) return -1;
    if(0>dup2(STDOUT_FILENO,tmp)) return -1; /*really shouldn't happen*/
    if(0>dup2(devnull,STDOUT_FILENO)) return -1; /*really shouldn't happen*/
    if(0>tmp=dup(devnull)) return -1; /*really shouldn't happen unless we're multithreaded and another thread steals the fd spot*/
}
```

Either solution depends on your code being single threaded.

In any case, well behaved library functions should leave files they don't own alone, unless you explicitly request them to do something with such files.